# Lost when trying to get good time series prediction results (regression problem) even after trying many things

Tags: regression, machine-learning, time-series, python, tensorflow

I'm not able to get good results after a long time testing when using TensorFlow to predict time series data (regression problem). I don't know if the problem is with the data (little quantity and/or low quality) or with the model (or if there is a problem with both) (although I have tried several and tested various combinations of hyperparameters). I'm really tired and I don't know what else to do. What would you do if you were in my place? Where could I find someone who can help me with this problem? Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Comment: Perhaps you should try statistical parametric time series models instead of machine learning methods. See the 'forecast' package in CRAN R, for example, and also look up Rob Hyndman's web site on forecasting.

Comment: @dnqxt ok, thanks, I'll look at these things.